# Area Under Curve 5 Year Prediction

Tags: python, scipy

I have a dataset that includes a ratio(y-axis) and tenure(x-axis). My goal is to take the training set and establish a learning curve by tenure (1 to 15 years) which looks like this:

Actual Group Average:

```
[array([0.38056266, 0.45929261, 0.53092972, 0.53245087, 0.55000385, 0.53092972,  0.6007738 , 0.54705655, 0.6120135 , 0.72657781, 0.48381324,
       0.64294081, 0.6181171 , 0.67747932, 0.5790196 , 0.58390105])
```

Given new data, let's say someone tenured for 3 years, is 0.64, previous year 0.53. I would need to predict the area under the curve for 5 years, or in year 8. For someone that is 5 years tenured then predict for year 10, and so on.

After I have the areas for the actual group curve above and the predicted curve for individual, I would take the difference of the two to rate for potential.

My question is, given tenures 1 through 15, how would I find the auc in 5 year intervals for both the predicted and actual group?